# Android/Java how to efficiently use multiple comparator in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have a `Java` class named `Friend`

```
public class Friend {   
    public String friendsUserName;
    public boolean isFavorite;
    public boolean isFriend;
}
```

I get `Json` file from the server containing `JsonArray` of this class `Friend`. I use `Gson` class to parse and map the `Json` to the `ArrayList<Friend>`.I have to sort the array in following manner

1. Top level elements are `Friend` who are `isFavorite` and `isFriend`
2. Then the `ArrayList` contains remaining `Friend` who are only `isFriend`
3. Finally the `ArrayList` contains `Friend` where `isFriend` is `False`.

So for that I can use the method described on this [ComparatorChain](http://strangeoptics.blogspot.com/2011/09/sorting-objects-by-multiple-attributes.html)

Or I can use the following way to properly sort the `ArrayList<Friend>`

```
 public ArrayList<Friend> friendsList;
 public void sortArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Friend> favoriteList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    ArrayList<Friend> friendOnlyList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    ArrayList<Friend> nonFriendList = new ArrayList<Friend>();

    for (int length = friendsList.size(), i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Friend friend = friendsList.get(i);
        if (friend.isFriend) {
            if (friend.isFavorite) {
                favoriteList.add(friend);
            } else {
                friendOnlyList.add(friend);
            }
        } else {
            nonFriendList.add(friend);
        }
        friendsList.remove(i);
    }
    addAllAndClear(favoriteList);
    favoriteList = null;

    addAllAndClear(friendOnlyList);
    friendOnlyList = null;
    addAllAndClear(nonFriendList);
    nonFriendList = null;

}

public void addAllAndClear(ArrayList<Friend> updatedList) {
    Collections.sort(updatedList, nameComparator);
    friendsList.addAll(updatedList);
    updatedList.clear();
    updatedList = null;

}

    Comparator<Friend> nameComparator = new Comparator<FriendListResponse.Friend>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Friend lhs, Friend rhs) {
        return lhs.friendsUserName.compareTo(rhs.friendsUserName);
    };
};
```

`Efficiency` wise which should I follow the `ComparatorChain` or my own method. I am developing this for `Android` platform,so `Memory Management` and `Efficiency` is of topmost priority.
  P.S. I am no good at using tools to compare `Efficiency`.

Comment: Other posters have already given potential solutions, but a good resource to refer to when optimizing for performance is the [Performance Tips article](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) offered in the Android Documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following comparator:

```
Comparator<Friend> favoriteComparator = new Comparator<FriendListResponse.Friend>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Friend lhs, Friend rhs) {
        int i=0,j=0;
        if(lhs.isFavorite()&&lhs.isFriend())
           i++;
        if(lhs.isFriend())
           i++;
        if(rhs.isFavorite()&&rhs.isFriend())
           j++;
        if(rhs.isFriend())
           j++; 
        return i-j;
    };
};
```

While sorting:

```
Collections.sort(friendsList,favoriteComparator);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,it works like a charm.And one thing, since I want the `List` to contain `Friend` who is both `isFavorite` and `isFriend` at top of the `List`,followed by `Friend` who is `isFriend` only and rest non friends.So for that I need to `return j-i` instead of `return i-j`

Comment: Is it possible to find the  from which `index` there is changing of `Friend` nature. For e.g. `A,B` are `Friend`who are fav and frnd, `C,D,E` are `Friend` who are frnd only and `F,G` are non frnd. So, the changing `indices` are `0 2 5`. I can do it easily from sorted list,but is it possible to do from above `comparator`.Meaning, sorting and keeping changed `indices` can be done at same time or not. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this comparator can be used to achieve this. You should simply apply a for loom on the sorted list and find the indexes.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely implement using `for loop` to the `sorted` `list`

Answer (score 2):

In your class **Friend** implement **Comparable** interface and then use **Collections.sort()**

Or as @vipul mittal suggest

Comparator may look like

```
Comparator<Friend> favoriteComparator = new Comparator<FriendListResponse.Friend>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Friend lhs, Friend rhs) {
        int i=0,j=0;
        if(lhs.isFavorite() && lhs.isFriend())
           i++;
        if(lhs.isFriend())
           i++;
        if(rhs.isFavorite() && rhs.isFriend())
           j++;
        if(rhs.isFriend())
           j++; 

        if (i==j) {
            return lhs.friendsUserName.compareTo(rhs.friendsUserName);
        }
        else {
            return i-j;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: this . The ComparatorChain is doing exactly this , only it take care of the chaining logic for you. All you need to do is place the logic handling isFavourite first and the one handling the isFriend last

Comment: @Unlink: Thanks for the answer and thanks for implementing the `compareTo(friendUserName)`